# Schema missing from eclipse plugin environment

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am getting this in my plugin perspective. I get a `generic` menu istead of specific items e.g. `action`, etc.
[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/images/plugin-error.jpg))</sub>

My "Preferences / Plugin development / Target platform" looks like :

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/images/plugin-target.jpg))</sub>

When I go to edit it looks like :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this similar to [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg01687.html)?

> I just figured out what was the problem.
>   **I was using an external target platform to run my plugins, where I had installed only the basic plugins**. 
>   After I installed the sources `org.eclipse.platform.source_2.1.0` and `org.eclipse.platform.win32.source_2.1.0` also on the target platform, the manifest editor in the PDE was working normal again.

(to be adapted to your Eclipse version)

---

Also confirmed in this [more recent thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg31636.html):

> > Your target platform (and the default will be your own eclipse install) needs to have the source bundles (which provide the schema files used by these menus).
> >
> > i.e. if I installed the runtime version, I will only get Generic in the menus but if I install the SDK version I will get real elements.
>
> Thank you very much for the answer.
>   I "Add" source file to the platform (`Preferences / Plugin development / Target platform`) and got all menus!!

Comment: Thanks, but how do I install the SDK version. I don't the "Add source" option, screen print attached above.

Comment: @fastcodejava: you should be able to edit the target Platform, go to the tab "Content" and click on "Add required" or select yourself the right packages.

Comment: I see `source` is included and `Add required` button is disabled. Is my environment totally messed up? Screen print attached above.